# Is there any way to maintain private data between peers using hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, privacy

I am trying to develop an application using fabric and composer. I had read that private data can be maintained using fabric chaincode, but i am curious to know that, is it possible to maintain private data between peers/channels/orgs using composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot use private data in hyperledger composer. Hyperledger Composer is now deprecated and is unlikely to deliver any further releases. The recommendation is to look at the apis provided by hyperledger fabric especially around fabric-network for client side code development and the contract api for node chaincode (smart contract) development.